# I need to construct a specific matrix, where some elements are matrices themselves [python]. Block tridiagonal matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I have that part of code that generates B and I:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse.linalg as sc

size = 10

#1. create the matrix B and I
def matrix(size):
    dx = size / (size - 1)
    B = np.identity(size ) * (-4)
    counter = 0
    sizeCounter = size
    for i in range(1, size):
        B[i, counter] = 1
        B[counter, i] = 1
        counter += 1
    B[0,:]=0
    B[:,0]=0
    B[size-1,:]=0
    B[:,size-1]=0

    I=np.identity(size)
    I[0,:]=0
    I[:,0]=0
    I[size-1,:]=0
    I[:,size-1]=0


    return B,I
```

I would like to generate a squared (size^2)x(size^2) matrix M. So if size is 10, M would be 100x100. M will have the following form at the picture attached.[image: M matrix, size=n]. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.concatenate` to build each row of your matrix of matrices.

```
B, I = matrix(size)
A = np.zeros((size, size))

M = []
for i in range(size):
    if i == 0:
        M.append(np.concatenate([ B, I, np.tile(A, (1, size-2)) ], axis = -1 ))
    elif i == size-1:
        M.append(np.concatenate([ np.tile(A, (1, size-2)), I, B ], axis = -1))
    else:
        M.append(np.concatenate([ np.tile(A, (1, i-1)), I, B, I, np.tile(A, (1, size-i-2))], axis = -1))
M = np.concatenate(M, axis = 0)
```

Using list comprehension:

```
M = np.concatenate([
        np.concatenate([ B, I, np.tile(A, (1, size-2)) ], axis = -1 ) if i == 0 else
        np.concatenate([ np.tile(A, (1, size-2)), I, B ], axis = -1) if i == size-1
        else np.concatenate([ np.tile(A, (1, i-1)), I, B, I, np.tile(A, (1, size-i-2))], axis = -1)
        for i in range(size)], axis = 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are three possibilities:

First, build the building blocks:

I'm using `einsum` to write the diagonals.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> 
>>> size = 6
>>> 
>>> O, B, I = OBI = np.zeros((3, size, size))
>>> np.einsum('ii->i', I[1:-1, 1:-1])[:] = 1
>>> np.einsum('ii->i', B[1:-1, 1:-1])[:] = -4
>>> np.einsum('ii->i', B[1:-2, 2:-1])[:] = 1
>>> np.einsum('ii->i', B[2:-1, 1:-2])[:] = 1
```

Next, build the container:

I'm using `toeplitz` to build the (scalar) tridiagonal matrix.

```
>>> from scipy import linalg
>>>
>>> T = np.zeros((size,), dtype=int)
>>> T[:2] = 1, 2
>>> T = linalg.toeplitz(T)
```

Solution 1:

Combine using `np.block`:

```
>>> M1 = np.block(list(map(list, OBI[T])))
```

Solution 2:

Combine using `reshape`:

```
>>> M2 = OBI[T].swapaxes(1, 2).reshape(size*size, size*size)
```

Solution 3:

Use `np.kron`:

```
>>> Tm1 = np.zeros((size,))
>>> Tm1[1] = 1
>>> Tm1 = linalg.toeplitz(Tm1)
>>> 
>>> M3 = np.kron(np.identity(size,), B) + np.kron(Tm1, I)
```